# Pandas group by with row-wise access to column data

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a csv that looks like this:

```
district_system_id,state_id_number,software_id,last_name,first_name,accommodation_type,accommodation_name,accommodation_additional_text
id_number,last_name,first_name,accommodation_type,accommodation_name,accommodation_additional_text
1,Adair,Brandon,Classroom-Based Assessment,Extended Time,
1,Adair,Brandon,District-Based Assessment,Other,"Test in smaller setting, separate location."
2,Auclair,Hattie,Classroom-Based Assessment,Limit matching questions to 5 items per section,
2,Auclair,Hattie,Classroom-Based Assessment,Other,Use manipulatives and/or numberline
2,Auclair,Hattie,Educational,Audiobooks,
```

The end goal is this, where the types and names (+extra text) have been swung into a single cell of HTML for display:

```
student_id,last_name,first_name,accommodations
2,Adair,Brandon,"<b>Classroom-Based Assessment</b><ul><li>Extended Time</li><li>Other (Test in smaller setting, separate location.)</li><li>Provide study guides and allow time for review</li><li>Reduce the number of choices on tests, quizzes</li><li>Tests read aloud</li></ul><b>District-Based Assessment</b><ul><li>Extended Time</li><li>Other (Test in smaller setting, separate location.)</li><li>Provide study guides and allow time for review</li><li>Reduce the number of choices on tests, quizzes</li><li>Tests read aloud</li></ul>"
3,Auclair,Hattie,"<b>Classroom-Based Assessment</b><ul><li>Limit matching questions to 5 items per section</li><li>Other (Use manipulatives and/or numberline)</li><li>Provide a word bank</li><li>Reduce the number of choices on tests, quizzes</li><li>Tests read aloud</li><li>Use a scribe</li></ul><b>Educational</b><ul><li>Accommodation (Independent work task station  visual timer (red, yellow, and green) - during transitions from work to break and break to work first/then visual Sensory/movement breaks items to blow on to help calm down (windmill, bubbles, pretend to blow up balloon) or star breathing Adaptive writing materials (pencil grips etc.) Communication notebook between home and school Use of manipulatives Schedule quick breaks to check for individual student comprehension Provide visuals and pictures for comprehension use of fidgets and weighted sensory materials (weighted vest, weighted lap pads) check ins for restrooms water at desk use of social stories use of zones of regulation speech to text on longer writing responses bathroom sequencing steps visual access to headphones as needed during sirens/fire alarms as needed use of books about anger management Special transportation - use of a harness )</li><li>Allow freedom to move about, stand, pace if needed</li><li>Allow frequent breaks</li><li>Audiobooks</li><li>Break lessons or directions into smaller units</li><li>Decrease amount (not content) of homework</li></ul>"
```

I've managed to get something working, but it just feels kind of clumsy to do it in so many steps.  I feel like there should be a way to do like a `df.groupby( [mykeys] ).agg(lambda x: aggregation using more than one column at a time)`

At any rate, here is how I approached it:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('accomms.csv')

# Combine accommodation_name and accommodation_additional_text
df['accommodation'] = df.apply(lambda x: "<li>" + x['accommodation_name'] + ( f" ({x['accommodation_additional_text']})" if not pd.isna(x['accommodation_additional_text']) else "") + "</li>", axis=1)

# Group by accommodation_type and join combined accommodation
df = df.groupby( by=['district_system_id', 'state_id_number', 'software_id', 'last_name', 'first_name', 'accommodation_type'] )[ ['accommodation'] ].agg(lambda x: "".join(sorted(x)) ).reset_index()

df
```

```
|    |   student_id | last_name   | first_name   | accommodation_type         | accommodation                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           |
|---:|-------------:|:------------|:-------------|:---------------------------|:------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  0 |            2 | Adair       | Brandon      | Classroom-Based Assessment | <li>Extended Time</li><li>Other (Test in smaller setting, separate location.)</li><li>Provide study guides and allow time for review</li><li>Reduce the number of choices on tests, quizzes</li><li>Tests read aloud</li>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               |
|  1 |            2 | Adair       | Brandon      | District-Based Assessment  | <li>Extended Time</li><li>Other (Test in smaller setting, separate location.)</li><li>Provide study guides and allow time for review</li><li>Reduce the number of choices on tests, quizzes</li><li>Tests read aloud</li>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               |
|  2 |            3 | Auclair     | Hattie       | Classroom-Based Assessment | <li>Limit matching questions to 5 items per section</li><li>Other (Use manipulatives and/or numberline)</li><li>Provide a word bank</li><li>Reduce the number of choices on tests, quizzes</li><li>Tests read aloud</li><li>Use a scribe</li>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           |
|  3 |            3 | Auclair     | Hattie       | Educational                | <li>Accommodation (Independent work task station  visual timer (red, yellow, and green) - during transitions from work to break and break to work first/then visual Sensory/movement breaks items to blow on to help calm down (windmill, bubbles, pretend to blow up balloon) or star breathing Adaptive writing materials (pencil grips etc.) Communication notebook between home and school Use of manipulatives Schedule quick breaks to check for individual student comprehension Provide visuals and pictures for comprehension use of fidgets and weighted sensory materials (weighted vest, weighted lap pads) check ins for restrooms water at desk use of social stories use of zones of regulation speech to text on longer writing responses bathroom sequencing steps visual access to headphones as needed during sirens/fire alarms as needed use of books about anger management Special transportation - use of a harness )</li><li>Allow freedom to move about, stand, pace if needed</li><li>Allow frequent breaks</li><li>Audiobooks</li><li>Break lessons or directions into smaller units</li><li>Decrease amount (not content) of homework</li> |
```

```py
# Combine accommodation_type and accommodation
df['accommodations'] = df.apply(lambda x: f"<b>{x['accommodation_type']}</b><ul>{x['accommodation']}</ul>", axis=1)

# Group by student and join combined accommodations
df = df.groupby( by=['district_system_id', 'state_id_number', 'software_id', 'last_name', 'first_name'] )[ ['accommodations'] ].agg(lambda x: "".join(sorted(x)) ).reset_index()

df
```

```
|    |   student_id | last_name   | first_name   | accommodations                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            |
|---:|-------------:|:------------|:-------------|:------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  0 |            2 | Adair       | Brandon      | <b>Classroom-Based Assessment</b><ul><li>Extended Time</li><li>Other (Test in smaller setting, separate location.)</li><li>Provide study guides and allow time for review</li><li>Reduce the number of choices on tests, quizzes</li><li>Tests read aloud</li></ul><b>District-Based Assessment</b><ul><li>Extended Time</li><li>Other (Test in smaller setting, separate location.)</li><li>Provide study guides and allow time for review</li><li>Reduce the number of choices on tests, quizzes</li><li>Tests read aloud</li></ul>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
|  1 |            3 | Auclair     | Hattie       | <b>Classroom-Based Assessment</b><ul><li>Limit matching questions to 5 items per section</li><li>Other (Use manipulatives and/or numberline)</li><li>Provide a word bank</li><li>Reduce the number of choices on tests, quizzes</li><li>Tests read aloud</li><li>Use a scribe</li></ul><b>Educational</b><ul><li>Accommodation (Independent work task station  visual timer (red, yellow, and green) - during transitions from work to break and break to work first/then visual Sensory/movement breaks items to blow on to help calm down (windmill, bubbles, pretend to blow up balloon) or star breathing Adaptive writing materials (pencil grips etc.) Communication notebook between home and school Use of manipulatives Schedule quick breaks to check for individual student comprehension Provide visuals and pictures for comprehension use of fidgets and weighted sensory materials (weighted vest, weighted lap pads) check ins for restrooms water at desk use of social stories use of zones of regulation speech to text on longer writing responses bathroom sequencing steps visual access to headphones as needed during sirens/fire alarms as needed use of books about anger management Special transportation - use of a harness )</li><li>Allow freedom to move about, stand, pace if needed</li><li>Allow frequent breaks</li><li>Audiobooks</li><li>Break lessons or directions into smaller units</li><li>Decrease amount (not content) of homework</li></ul> |
```

It gives me exactly what I want, but it feels that could be joined together a little easier.  Is there something in the group by/aggregation realm that lets you have row-wise access to the columns so they can be combined while being aggregated?